# How would I make my wave system work with multiple types of enemies like for Speeders, Normals

Tags: roblox

I made a wave system but I forgot to make it work with multiple types of enemies, I have tried a couple of times but it lead to no avail. It also keeps spawning 1-2 more zombies than it says in the code.

```
local module = require(game:GetService("ServerScriptService")["Wave"])
while wait(0.1) do
    if #game.Workspace.Enemies:GetChildren() == 0 then
        -- WAVE HAS STARTED
        module.Wave = module.Wave + 1
        module.SpawnEnemy(module.EnemyWave[module.Wave][2], module.EnemyWave[module.Wave][3])
    end
end
```

Module Script:

```
local module = {
    EnemyWave = {
    {1, "Normal", 4},
    {2, "Normal", 8},
    {3, "Speeder", 4},
    {4, {
            {
                "Normal", 8
            },
            {
                "Speedier", 6
            }
    }}
    },
    Wave = 0
}
local Assets = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage").Assets
function module.SpawnEnemy(Enemy: string, Count: number)
    for i = 1,Count,1 do
        wait(0.2)
        local enemy = Assets[string.format(Enemy, i)]:Clone()
        enemy.Parent = game.Workspace.Enemies
    end
end
return module
```